# Financial Planning Price Quote Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

After a lot of confusing research, I've given up trying to figure out how to write the code for a project I'm working on and I am hoping someone can help me out.

I need to create an HTML price quote block for a client's website. The formula needs to be able to do this:

```
(Income * 0.01) + ((Property Value + Investments - Debt)*0.005)
```

So the variables are Income, Property Value, Investments, and Debt. The output needs to be in dollars ($) and should be a minimum of 150. In other words, if someone type in values that would equal less than 150, it should display 150.

My attempt is below.
What's going wrong?

```js
function calculatePrice(myform){

  //Get selected data 
  var elt = document.getElementById(“income");
  var elt = document.getElementById(“property");
  var elt = document.getElementById(“investments");
  var elt = document.getElementById("debt");
    

    
  //convert data to integers
  income = parseInt(income);
  property = parseInt(property);
  investments = parseInt(investments);
  investments = parseInt(debt);
    
  //calculate total value  
var result=Math.max(income * 0.01 + (property + investments - debt)*0.005, 150);
    
  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=total;

}
```

```html
<FORM Name="myform">

  <div>
    <label for="income">Yearly Income</label>
    <input id="income" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="property">Estimated Value of your Asstes (house, land, etc.)</label>
    <input id="property" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="investments">Estimated Value of Investments (stocks, bonds, IRA, etc.)</label>
    <input id="investments" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="debt">Estimated Debt (mortgage, loans, credit cards)</label>
    <input id="debt" type="text">
  </div>

</FORM>

<button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button> The new calculated price:
<INPUT type="text" id="PicExtPrice" Size=8>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaredbelcher/9h72s0z0/)

Comment: What code did you try and what specifically went wrong?

Comment: Ok so this is what I have so far. Again, I have no idea what I'm doing here and so any help would be much appreciated.

[link]https://jsfiddle.net/jaredbelcher/9h72s0z0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base formula should look something like this:

```
var result=Math.max(Income * 0.01 + (PropertyValue + Investments - Debt)*0.005, 150);
```

assuming that the variables already contain the numerical values from your relevant input fields. You still need to make sure that this calculation is triggered each time one of the input fields is changed (or each time a key has been released) and that the result gets written back into a suitable place on your HTML page. All that is easily done with a few jquery commands.

When writing it back to your page you should probably also round the result to two decimal places using something like `result.toFixed(2)`.

**Edit**

I have transferred your JSfifddle to an internal SO-fiddle. There were several small points wrong with your code. Have a look at the following and find the differences:

```js
function getv(id){return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value||0);}
function calculatePrice(myform){
  // calculate result:
  var result=Math.max(getv('income') * 0.01 + (getv('property') 
           + getv('investments') - getv('debt'))*0.005, 150);
  // place the output into the target field:
  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=result;

}
```

```html
<FORM Name="myform">

<div>
 <label for="income">Yearly Income</label>
 <input id="income" type="text">
</div>

<div>
 <label for="property">Estimated Value of your Asstes (house, land, etc.)</label>
 <input id="property" type="text">
</div>

<div>
 <label for="investments">Estimated Value of Investments (stocks, bonds, IRA, etc.)</label>
 <input id="investments" type="text">
</div>

<div>
 <label for="debt">Estimated Debt (mortgage, loans, credit cards)</label>
 <input id="debt" type="text">
</div>

</FORM>

<button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button>

The new calculated price:<INPUT type="text" id="PicExtPrice" Size=8>
```

To make things easier I defined an little "getter" function to retrieve the input field values. I just hate repeating myself when I am coding. So, `getv()` returns a float value for any input-id given. The formula is unchanged, but in your final line you tried to refer to an indefined variable `total`, when it should have been `result`.

Another issue might have been some quotation marks, like in `document.getElementById(“income")`. Notice: the first `“` is wrong and should be a plain `"` instead.

**final edit**:

To make the calculation a little more "forgiving" I added the `||0` after `document.getElementById(id).value`. The `0` now steps in whenever the input field was untouched (and returned an empty string). And I could not resist shortening the whole thing again. Who needs the individual variables for `income`, `property` and so on? This is just unnecessary fluff, when the main formula can be written by directly using the `getv()` function.

Comment: Ok so this is what I have so far. Again, I have no idea what I'm doing here and so any help would be much appreciated.

[link]https://jsfiddle.net/jaredbelcher/9h72s0z0/